# How do you use several variables and get several answers from one function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I've been learning JavaScript for a college assignment and I can't figure out why my point counters don't work.

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Team points counter</TITLE>
    <script>
    <!-- Variable assignments brick -->
    var T1, T2, T3, T4, T5;
    T1 = 0;
    T2 = 0;
    T3 = 0;
    T4 = 0;
    T5 = 0;
    <!-- Function brick -->
    function Add(Tx, TxAns) {
        return function() {
        Tx += 1;
        document.getElementById("TxAns").innerHTML = Tx;
        }
    }
    function Sub(Tx,TxAns) {
        return function() {
        Tx += 1;
        document.getElementById("TxAns").innerHTML = Tx;
        }
    }
    </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <h1 id="Subtitle">Team points counter</h1>
    <!-- Button brick -->
    <p id = "T1p"> Team 1 &nbsp
    <button id=Team1A type="button" onclick="Add(T1,T1Ans);"> +1 </button>
    <button id=Team1S type="button" onclick="Sub(T1,T1Ans);"> -1 </button> </p>
    <p> <output id="T1Ans"> </output> </p>
    <p id = "T2p"> Team 2 &nbsp
    <button id=Team2A type="button" onclick="Add(T2,T2Ans);"> +1 </button>
    <button id=Team2S type="button" onclick="Sub(T2,T2Ans);"> -1 </button> </p>
    <p> <output id="T2Ans"> </output> </p>
    <p id = "T3p"> Team 3 &nbsp
    <button id=Team3A type="button" onclick="Add(T3,T3Ans);"> +1 </button>
    <button id=Team3S type="button" onclick="Sub(T3,T3Ans);"> -1 </button> </p>
    <p> <output id="T3Ans"> </output> </p>
    <p id = "T4p"> Team 4 &nbsp
    <button id=Team4A type="button" onclick="Add(T4,T4Ans);"> +1 </button>
    <button id=Team4S type="button" onclick="Sub(T4,T5Ans);"> -1 </button> </p>
    <p> <output id="T4Ans"> </output> </p>
    <p id = "T5p"> Team 5 &nbsp
    <button id=Team5A type="button" onclick="Add(T5,T5Ans);"> +1 </button>
    <button id=Team5S type="button" onclick="Sub(T5,T5Ans);"> -1 </button> </p>
    <p> <output id="T5Ans"> </output> </p>
    </BODY>
    <script>
    <!-- CSS brick -->
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    document.getElementById("Subtitle").style.color = "Black";
    document.getElementById("T1p").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("T2p").style.color = "orange";
    document.getElementById("T3p").style.color = "yellow";
    document.getElementById("T4p").style.color = "green";
    document.getElementById("T5p").style.color = "blue";
    </script>
</HTML>
```

I tried making a different program to figure out why at it seems that when I try to make the function availible for several variables, it stops working.

```
<HTML>
    <SCRIPT>
    T1 = 0;
    function Add(Tx){
        Tx += 1;
        document.getElementById("Tx").innerHTML = Tx;
    }
    </SCRIPT>
    <BUTTON type="button" onclick="Add(T1);"> +1 </BUTTON>
    <OUTPUT id=Tx> </OUTPUT>
</HTML>
```

Now this only allows itself to be added to once.

Any and all help would be appreciated

Comment: It is starting from before right?

Comment: You can't pass pure types by reference with JS, but objects are passed by reference.  So what I would do is put your `T1, T2` etc into an object, and then pass the prop name, eg. `T1` to your function.

Comment: `Tx += 1` - this is only changing the value of the parameter `Tx` inside the function. `Add(T1)` passes the _value_ of `T1` at that time, but once you are inside the function, there is no connection to this outside variable any more. Therefor, `T1` never changes, and so you are calling your function with the same starting value each time.

Comment: Right, nothing is going to interpret "Tx" as meaning "T1" or "T2" or whatever. That's not how the language works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of using an Object to keep track of the totals.

I've also modified you code to be a bit more DRY.  Instead of creating lots of HTML for each one, I place the HTML inside a hidden DIV to act like a template, and then use Javascript to create the real ones.  From here I can then easily attach the event to the buttons.

```js
const answers = {
  T1: 0,  T2: 0,  T3: 0,  T4: 0,  T5: 0
};

const mount = document.querySelector('#mount');
const template = document.querySelector("#team_template");

function TeamInput(o) {
  const f = document.createElement('div');
  f.innerHTML = template.innerHTML;
  const p = f.querySelector('p');
  p.style.color = o.color;
  const output = f.querySelector('output');
  const buttons = p.querySelectorAll('button');
  f.querySelector('span').innerText = o.name;
  //add button
  buttons[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
    answers[o.T] += 1;
    console.log(answers);
    output.innerText = answers[o.T];
  });
  //substract
  buttons[1].addEventListener('click', () => {
    answers[o.T] -= 1;
   output.innerText = answers[o.T];
  });
  //add to DOM
  mount.appendChild(f);
}

document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
document.getElementById("Subtitle").style.color = "Black";

TeamInput({name: 'Team 1', color: 'red', T: 'T1'});
TeamInput({name: 'Team 2', color: 'orange', T: 'T2'});
TeamInput({name: 'Team 3', color: 'yellow', T: 'T3'});
TeamInput({name: 'Team 4', color: 'green',T: 'T4'});
TeamInput({name: 'Team 5', color: 'blue',T: 'T5'});
```

```html
<h1 id="Subtitle">Team points counter</h1>
<div id="mount"></div>

<div id="team_template" style="display:none">
  <p><span>Name</span>&nbsp
    <button type="button"> +1 </button>
    <button type="button"> -1 </button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <output>0</output>
  </p>
</div>
```